# I am trying to use awk to extract a portion of each line in my file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a large file of user agent strings, and I want to extract one particular section of each request.

For input:

```
207.46.13.9 - - [22/Jan/2019:08:02:29 +0330] "GET /product/23474/%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%B2%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86%DA%AF%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-Remington-Laser-Hair-Removal-IPL6250 HTTP/1.1" 200 41766 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"
```

I am trying to get output:

```
23474
```

from after `/product/` in the sample above.

I'm trying to use Awk, but I can't figure out how to get the regex expression that's required for this. I'm sure it's simpler than I think, but I'm quite new to this!

The pattern is the following:

```
RANDOMSTUFF/GET /product/XXXXX/MORERANDOMSTUFF
```

and I'm trying to grab `XXXXX`. I don't think I can use just the '/' since there will be other slashes in the line.

I've tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[GET \\/product\\/]"}{print $2}'
```

to try and use `GET /product` as a field separator, and then grab the next item. But I've realized this won't work (even if I got the regex expression right, which I didn't), since there might not be whitespace after the product ID I want to grab.

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail? The regex for four digits between slashes is `\/[0-9]{4}\/`. Maybe see also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which has some basic FAQs as well as links to learning and reference materials.

Comment: The incorrect square brackets are another common beginner error which is explained in some detail on the page I linked to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets you tried to put around the `FS` are incorrect here, but the problem after you fix that is that you then simply have two fields, as you are overriding the splitting on whitespace which Awk normally does.

Because the (horrible) date format always has exactly two slashes, I think you can actually do

```sh
awk -F / '/product/ { print $5 }' filename
```

Even though it divides the earlier part of the line into quite weird parts, the things after `GET` or `PUT` will always be `$4`, `$5`, etc.

If you wanted to keep your original idea, maybe try

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS="GET /product/"}
  NF==2{
    # second field is now everything after /product/ -- split on slash
    split($2, f, "/")
    print f[1] }' file
```

... or very simply, brutally remove everything except the text you want;

```sh
awk '/\/product\// { sub(".*/product/", ""), sub("/.*", ""); print }' file
```

which might be better expressed as a simple `sed` script;

```sh
sed -n 's%.*GET /product/\([^/]*\)/.*%\1%p' file
```

Comment: So this worked great for some of the lines, but with lines that had different formatting than this one, it wasn't right. But thank you for the guidance, I'll try and use this as a starting place. But I guess there's no simple way to indicate that I want to print everything between 'GET /product' and '/' in each line?

Comment: Sure you can, but please edit your question to show enough samples so we can see the corner cases which currently fail.

Comment: Okay, I'll add a few more samples, but there's just a ton of different formats unfortunately! 

Regarding your second suggestion, I wasn't able to get it to work, it gave me the following error:

awk: cmd. line:2: FS=GET /product/

awk: cmd. line:2:                 ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed a variable name.

Comment: I used your sed idea and combined it with some awk piping to get what I wanted! It's ugly, but it works, thanks for your help.